# Network Error on searchbox component reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm trying to create a searchbox that will render all products based on search value, but everytime i write something in the searchbox. Network Error will happen.

My searchbox:

```
<div className="site-header__search medium-down--hide large--right">
          <form
            method="post"
            className="input-group search-bar"
            id="search_box"
            role="search"
            style={{ position: "relative" }}
          >
            <input
              type="search"
              name="q"
              value={searchbox}
              onChange={(e) => setSearchbox(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Tìm kiếm..."
              className="input-group-field"
              aria-label="Tìm kiếm..."
              autocomplete="off"
            />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" className="btn icon-fallback-text">
                <span
                  className="sprite sprite-search"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span className="fallback-text"></span>
              </button>
            </span>

            <ProductSearch search={searchbox} />
          </form>
        </div>
```

My product search component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import productservice from "../../services/ProductService";
import urlImage from "../../config";

function ProductSearch(props) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(
    function () {
      (async function () {
        await productservice
          .getSearchResult(props.search)
          .then(function (result) {
            setProducts(result.data.products);
          });
      })();
    },
    [props.search]
  );
  const have_result = products == null ? "none" : "block";
  return (
    <ul
      className="search-results"
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 37,
        display: { have_result },
      }}
    >
      {(() => {
        if (products != null) {
          return products.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                <Link to={`/san-pham/chi-tiet/${product.slug}`}>
                  <span className="thumbnail">
                    <img
                      src={urlImage + "product_back/" + product.back_image}
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </span>
                  <span className="title">{product.name}</span>
                </Link>
              </li>
            );
          });
        }
      })()}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default ProductSearch;
```

My search function in laravel:

```
public function ProductBySearchBox($search){
        $products = Product::where('slug', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->get();
    if(count($products) > 0){
        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Tải dữ liệu thành công',
                'products' => $products,
            ],
            200
        );
    }
    return response()->json(
        [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Không có',
            'products' => null,
        ],
        200
    );
    }
```

I'm excepting a list of products will return below my searchbox if the search function return something.

Comment: What error do you receive exactly? You have a stacktrace?